# Connecting Windows PostgreSQL Server from pgAdmin III in Ubuntu 14.04.3

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu

I am trying to connect to PostgreSQL 9.4 Server on Windows platform from pgAdmin which is installed in Ubuntu 14.04.3 (Oracle Vbox).

First of all, I had to put an entry in pg_hba.conf file in Windows to be able to connect from other host. The line was:
"host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5"

Now, when I try to connect I receive an error alert with the message :"An error has ocurred: Error connecting to the server:"

I am looking for a log in Ubuntu to check what was the problem.

Any one can help me?

I am using default user "postgres".

Thanks.

Comment: if you have pgAdmin on linux, then you have psql. try psql -h WINDOWS_POSTGRES_HOST -U USERNAME

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was related to the Windows Firewall.

I created a rule to enable the traffic through port 5432 and now works.